# Check if option and radio input are selected and display different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check the reliability of the form showing percentage of reliability(like progress bar of password)

I have more radio inputs and select option and I want to display a div if one element over "n" is selected, a different div if 2 elements over "n-1" are selected(and hide the old one) and so on. How can I do it with javascript?

```
 <select id="type1" name="type1" class="insert_select">
   <option value="9999">-- empty --</option>
   <option value="0">product1</option>
   <option value="1">product2</option>
   <option value="3">product3</option>
   <option value="2">product4</option>                                        
 </select>


<input type="radio" id="yes_no" name="yes_no" value="1" class="radiobox">
```

Comment: What is `n`?  Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: for examble here there are a "select" and a "radio input" so if no one are selected I want to display a div, if one over 2 is selected I want to display a div hiding the old one, if 2 over 2 are selected... like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/db17mjow/) but not with input text

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but how are you planning on selecting multiple options from the dropdown?  You also have a radio button where it looks like you are after a checkbox.

Comment: here there are only 2 things to select: radio and dropdown menu so n is equal to 2. so if an option is selected from the dropdown menu, no matter what, I want to display a div with 50%, if the option form dropdown menu is selected and also the radio button I want to display a div with 100% (like a progress bar).

Comment: mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/dzqz2joq/ or http://jsfiddle.net/dzqz2joq/1/`jQuery`

Comment: more or less. Let me explain better: I have a form with "100" optional field (text, radio, dropdown menu...) for each field, if is selected/filled I want to display a progress bar(so different div) showing and hiding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of things you are after something like below.  I've use the link you put in the comments as a base to work from.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input, select").change(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        $("input, select").each(function (index, element) {
            var value = $(element).val();

            if ($(element).is('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]')) {
                if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else if(value.trim() !== "" && value !== "9999"){
                counter++;
            }
        });

        $("#div_1, #div_2, #div_3, #div_4, #div_5").hide();

        $("#div_"+counter).show(); 
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaw5zaz2/).

Comment: yes,thanks, this is what I was talking about!